# Classic Mode and Module Mode of Vuex Store - NuxtJS

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

I'm confused of Classic Mode and Module Mode of Vuex Store, I dont have the difference between this both. Now I'm using Classic Mode and I have intend to switch to Module Mode.

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/

Please show me the difference of two modes and what is the better choice?

Answer (score 0):

Vuex https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html explains this quite clear:

"Vuex allows us to divide our store into modules. Each module can contain its own state, mutations, actions, getters, and even nested modules"

Answer (score 0):

Module mode of vuex is confusing because official documentation is clear.

I searched for proper documentation, but couldnt find one, however come across this video on youtube.

Though language is not English, you still get the idea.

The concept is explained with'a simple example.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chnHCJz6xK8&t=896s

Hope this will help.